# ejabberd: can't seem to enable Stream Management

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Heyo,

I'm having a bit of a headache trying to get Stream Management (XEP-0198) working in ejabberd 17.04 in Ubuntu 16.10, though I've had this problem since ejabberd 17.03, and in spite of searching just about everywhere, I can't seem to get find a straight answer beyond either explicitly adding `stream_management: true` to my config or leaving it out and letting that setting default to `true`. None of which seem to be offering any success, however.

My only indication that Stream Management isn't working at the moment is via the Android app Conversations, which lists the extension as `Unavailable`, though the app picks up the extension from another server just fine. I can't seem to see any errors in ejabberd's logs either, barring the one time I caused a syntax error that's since been corrected.

This is my current config (yes, I know, it's adapted form a sample and I need to clean some junk out):

```
##
###             ejabberd configuration file
###         Archipel Sample default condiguration

define_macro:
    'CERT_LOCATION': "/certs/live/social.diskseven.com/ejabberd.pem"
    'DH_PARAMS':     "/certs/live/social.diskseven.com/dhparams.pem"

###     =========
###     DEBUGGING

# Increase this if you want sone insane erlang debug
loglevel: 3

###     ================
###     SERVED HOSTNAMES

# Change it for you FQDN
hosts:
    - "xmpp.diskseven.com"

###     ===============
###     LISTENING PORTS

listen:
    -
      #it's a good idea to put xmlrpc behing a reverse proxy
      #because you can't use tls directly, make it listen to localhost
      ip: "::1"
      # and read the Security section on the wiki
      port: 4560
      module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
      access_commands:
            xmlrpcaccess:
                all : []


## ejabberd c2s
    -
      ip: "::"
      port: 5222
      stream_management: true
      module: ejabberd_c2s
      resend_on_timeout: if_offline

      ##
      ## If you installed a SSL
      ## certificate, specify the full path to the
      ## file and uncomment this line:
      ##

      certfile: 'CERT_LOCATION'
      starttls: true
      starttls_required: true
      ciphers: "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
      protocol_options:
       - "no_sslv2"
       - "no_sslv3"
       - "no_tlsv1"
       - "no_tlsv1_1"
      max_stanza_size: 65536000
      shaper: c2s_shaper
      access: c2s

## ejabbed s2s
    -
      ip: "::"
      port: 5269
      module: ejabberd_s2s_in
      max_stanza_size: 65536000

## ejabberd http/s and websocket/s
    -
      ip: "::"
      port: 5280
      module: ejabberd_http
      request_handlers:
        "/xmpp": ejabberd_http_ws
      # if you want to use starttls with websock
      # the URI will be wss://
      # please be sure that the certificate belong
      # to a trusted AC in your browser
      certfile: 'CERT_LOCATION'
      dhfile: 'DH_PARAMS'
      # tls: true
      web_admin: true
      http_bind: true

###     ===
###     S2S
s2s_access: all
s2s_use_starttls: required
s2s_certfile: 'CERT_LOCATION' #concantinated cert.
s2s_dhfile: 'DH_PARAMS'
s2s_ciphers: "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
s2s_protocol_options:
 - "no_sslv2" 
 - "no_sslv3"
 - "no_tlsv1"
 - "no_tlsv1_1"


## domain_certfile: Specify a different certificate for each served hostname.
##
##host_config:
##   "xmpp.diskseven.com":
##     domain_certfile: 'CERT_LOCATION'
##   "conference.xmpp.diskseven.com":
##     domain_certfile: 'CERT_LOCATION'

###     ==============
###     AUTHENTICATION

auth_method: internal

###     ===============
###     TRAFFIC SHAPERS

shaper:
  # in B/s
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000000

###     ====================
###     ACCESS CONTROL LISTS

acl:
    admin:
        user:
            - "admin": "xmpp.diskseven.com"
    local:
        user_regexp: ""


###     ============
###     ACCESS RULES

access:
    max_user_sessions:
        all: 5
    local:
        local: allow
    c2s:
        blocked: deny
        all: allow
    c2s_shaper:
        admin: none
        all: fast
    s2s_shaper:
        all: fast
    s2s_access:
        all: allow
    announce:
        admin: allow
    configure:
        admin: allow
    muc_admin:
        admin: allow
    muc_create:
        local: allow
    muc:
        all: allow
    pubsub_createnode:
        all: allow
    register:
        all: deny
    xmlrpcaccess:
        admin : allow

### Frequency of account registration
registration_timeout: 600

###     ================
###     DEFAULT LANGUAGE

language: "en"

###     =======
###     MODULES

modules:
    mod_adhoc: []
    mod_announce:
        access: announce
    mod_blocking: []
    mod_caps: []
    mod_client_state: []
    mod_carboncopy: []
    mod_configure: []
    mod_disco: []
    mod_http_bind:
        max_inactivity: 400 # timeout valie for BOSH usefull for a large number of VM
    mod_http_upload: []
    mod_irc: []
    mod_last: []
    mod_mam: []
    mod_muc:
        host: "conference.@HOST@"
        access: all
        access_create: muc_create
        access_persistent: muc_create
        access_admin: muc_admin
    mod_offline: []
    mod_privacy: []
    mod_private: []
    mod_pubsub:
        access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
        ignore_pep_from_offline: true
        last_item_cache: false
        max_items_node: 1000
        plugins:
            - "flat"
            - "hometree"
            - "pep"
        pep_mapping:
            "urn:xmpp:microblog:0": "mb"
    mod_ping:
        send_pings: true
        ping_interval: 60
        ping_ack_timeout: 30
        timeout_action: kill
    mod_register:
        access: register
    mod_roster:
        versioning: true
    mod_shared_roster: []
    mod_time: []
    mod_vcard: []
    mod_version: []
    mod_admin_extra: []
#    mod_fail2ban:
#        c2s_auth_ban_lifetime: 1300
#        c2s_max_auth_failures: 5
```

Comment: android client also have enabled stream management? if not then you have to enable it client side also.

Comment: I haven't yet found any setting within the app that toggles stream management, and I imagine that the developer of the app has enabled it, since it's picking up the extension just fine on a completely different server (one that is being run by someone else) without any input to the app from myself.

Answer (score 0):

In ejabberd 17.03+ stream management is implemented as a separate module: `mod_stream_mgmt`. You should have read release notes ;)

Comment: Or ejabberd's developers could update the documentation to reflect this for new installs. Your needlessly condescending response is noted, though. :^)